# How do I make my background-image responsive so that it displays properly on iphones and android

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design

This is where the background is in my css. The picture fits perfectly like this, and I don't want to change the position or size or anything in normal browser. I just want the image to resize itself when viewed on phone devices or tablets.

```
.intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../img/mee.JPG) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0px 1px;
}
```

This is the html part:

```
 <!-- Intro Header -->
    <header class="intro">
        <div class="intro-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
                        <h1 class="brand-heading">Welcome</h1>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                        <font size= "6"><marquee behavior="slide" scrollamount ="22"><b>ENGINEER</font></marquee>
                        <font size= "6"><marquee behavior="slide" scrollamount ="20"><b>DEVELOPER</b></font></b></marquee>
                        <font size= "6"><marquee behavior="slide" scrollamount ="18"><b>COFFEE ADDICT</b></font></b></marquee>
                        </div>
                      <div class="buttonn">
                        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>

                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create additional css for different screen size, essentially making it responsive.

This is a great link explaining that and how to go about it: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en#a-note-on-min-device-width

The CSS used most often for responsive web design are min-width, max-width, min-height and max-height.

Hope that was helpful :)